# Programmatically connecting to a wifi network in Linux

Tags: linux, wifi

There are multiple questions regarding this functionality for Android or iOS, but I am attempting to do this on Linux (OpenWrt 15.05 to be specific). I want to scan for wireless networks, present the list to the user, have them select one and send the username/password to the network.

I wrote a quick C program using iw_scan from the wireless_tools package so I can see the wireless networks, but I am having issues trying to determine how to connect to a wireless network. iwconfig from the same package just appears to modify an already existing connection.

I have spent a few hours surfing the web thinking there has got to be a package that already does this since it is such a common use case. Anyone know of one?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure, but may `wicd` be something useful for you? Also [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92799/connecting-to-wifi-network-through-command-line).

Answer (score 2):

**wpa_supplicant**

Take a look at [wpa_supplicant](http://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/) package. It includes `wpa_supplicant` daemon that can be controlled via `wpa_cli` and `wpa_gui` utilities or [D-Bus API](https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/dbus.html).

Programs like `wicd` and `Network Manager` uses `wpa_supplicant` internally.

---

**NetworkManager**

You can also use [D-Bus API](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/unstable/spec.html) or command line interface (`nmcli`) for [`NetworkManager`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager). It provides a higher level abstraction than `wpa_supplicant` does.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at those utilities.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried number of solutions to this, from `wicd`, to network manager's cli interface `nmcli`, to [wifi](http://wifi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in python. I didn't want a UI, I didn't want network manager, and the python wifi project was too complicated and I faced some problems with it. So I wrote a short, simple bash script for connecting to wpa and open networks (WEP not supported), a wrapper on `wpa_passphrase` and `wpa_supplicant`:

```
sudo apt-get install -y wireless-tools wpasupplicant expect macchanger
sudo wget -O /usr/local/bin/wifi-connect https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erjoalgo/erjoalgo-gnu-scripts/master/wifi-connect
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wifi-connect
wifi-connect -e Internet -p my-password
wifi-connect -h
```

The wpa-passphrase files (including plaintext passphrases) are persisted in `$HOME/.config/wifi-connect`, and if no ESSID is provided, it will automatically connect to any known available network. It supports changing the iface mac address via macchanger.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Set Wi-Fi credentials
ssid="your_wifi_name"
pass="your_wifi_password"

# Check Wi-Fi connection status
if nmcli d | grep 'wifi' | grep -q "$ssid"; then
    echo "Wi-Fi already connected."
else
    echo "Wi-Fi not connected. Connecting to $ssid."
    # Connect to the preferred Wi-Fi if not connected
    nmcli device wifi connect "$ssid" password "$pass"
fi
```

See more about [nmcli](https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html)